# Worldpay WorldpayException (400) CVC can't be null/empty

Tags: php, laravel-4, worldpay

I have implemented world pay by using php sdk, i have set `Worldpay.useTemplateForm({'reusable':true,})`,it's working as I tried to use the generated token for my first order. My code is

```
$worldpay = new Worldpay('T_S_a61fda99-5c06-47fb-abc4-113db39c09d7');
$obj = array(
    "token" => "my-generated-toke", //worldpay.js 
    "orderDescription" => "your-order-description", 
    "amount" => 500, 
    "currencyCode" => "GBP",
    'name' => '',
    'reusable'=>true
);
```

But as I try for second order using the same token, it give me the following error:

> Worldpay WorldpayException (400)  CVC can't be null/empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, please just login into world pay account with your credentials and then click on the following link.

https://online.worldpay.com/settings/risk

From there just turn off "Card Security Code check", So then you can reuse your token for multiple time.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing this, This disables the check of the 3 digit security code on the back of the card and reduces security.

Comment: I am agree with you Scriptable but in my case i need to store the card token in the database, and then later this token will be uses again and again, so if we keep this option turn on, then it will need to refresh the token for cvc for every new order, which is quite annoying.

Comment: @user1875774 "quite annoying" - I think PCI compliance is quite annoying but I also like to know that my card details can't be spammed!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to disable the CSC feature, however Worldpay is not allowed to store the CVC number. So before each order request you should call:

```
curl https://api.worldpay.com/v1/tokens/[your token] 
-H "Content-type: application/json" 
-X PUT 
-d '{
        "cvc": "123",           
        "clientKey": "T_C_client_key"   
}'
```

Otherwise the next time you try and use that token it'll fail.

Why you can't pass the CVC along with the order request beats me.

https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/api#cvcfortoken

Comment: This states not to use this in code as we're then able to see the CVC... WHich is better than turning it off. Just a caveat to be aware of.